# Get selected language of default TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have implemented tts in my android app. It supports all languages which is supported by default TTS in android device. But is it possible to get the name of language which is selected in default TTS i.e name of language which is selected in Google TTS in the Settings?

Comment: tts.getDefaultLanguage()

Answer (score 5):

Until API 18, you would have to use [`getLanguage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getLanguage%28%29).

In API 18 [`getDefaultLanguage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getDefaultLanguage%28%29) was introduced.

And starting with API 21, you should use [`getDefaultVoice()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getDefaultVoice%28%29).[`getLocale()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/Voice.html#getLocale%28%29).

Comment: To the downvoter: care to mention what the issue is? If I'm wrong, I'd be more than happy to know the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: You are mostly correct. However, you forgot to address the question explicitly. The question was about getting the name of the language. Another thing you didn't point out is that `getLanguage()`, although being the only method available on older devices, does not return the default language. It will return the last language set on tts so you must careful when using it as the `Locale` values returned might be inconsistent with the default.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

Comment: its not working , it fetch the name of language which is selected in Language not in text to speech-> language

Comment: thx it works for for me to get default language